# What activities sections refer to in serverless step functions plugin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, serverless-framework, aws-step-functions

[Here](https://serverless.com/plugins/serverless-step-functions/) is a configuration snippet:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello

stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    hellostepfunc1:
      events:
        - http:
            path: gofunction
            method: GET
        - schedule:
            rate: rate(10 minutes)
            enabled: true
            input:
              key1: value1
              key2: value2
              stageParams:
                stage: dev
      name: myStateMachine
      definition:
        Comment: "A Hello World example of the Amazon States Language using an AWS Lambda Function"
        StartAt: HelloWorld1
        States:
          HelloWorld1:
            Type: Task
            Resource:
              Fn::GetAtt: [hello, Arn]
            End: true
      dependsOn: CustomIamRole
      tags:
        Team: Atlantis
      alarms:
        topics:
          ok: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:1234567890:NotifyMe
          alarm: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:1234567890:NotifyMe
          insufficientData: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:1234567890:NotifyMe
        metrics:
          - executionsTimeOut
          - executionsFailed
          - executionsAborted
          - metric: executionThrottled
            treatMissingData: breaching # overrides below default
        treatMissingData: ignore # optional
    hellostepfunc2:
      definition:
        StartAt: HelloWorld2
        States:
          HelloWorld2:
            Type: Task
            Resource:
              Fn::GetAtt: [hello, Arn]
            End: true
      dependsOn:
        - DynamoDBTable
        - KinesisStream
        - CUstomIamRole
      tags:
        Team: Atlantis
  activities:
    - myTask
    - yourTask
  validate: true # enable pre-deployment definition validation (disabled by default)

plugins:
  - serverless-step-functions
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
```

What does this mean?

```
  activities:
    - myTask
    - yourTask
```

With quick test search on page I have found no results. Any idea?

**UPDATED**

Some links with docs:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-activities.html
2. https://github.com/theburningmonk/complete-guide-to-step-functions-examples/blob/master/Activities/serverless.yml

But any way it is unclear what is activities section. Is it just place holder? Or serverless can package activities like lambda functions and deploy?

Comment: You can checkout aws doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-activities.html plus here's example on github: https://github.com/theburningmonk/complete-guide-to-step-functions-examples/blob/master/Activities/serverless.yml

Comment: Thank a lot! But it is still unclear how serverless process this entity :) The Question updated.